# combinatorics coloring problem

Tags: combinatorics

A coloring of all plane points with coordinates belonging to the set $S=\{0,1,...,n \}$ into red and white colors is said to be reddish if for each $i,j \in S $ at least one of four points $ (i,j),(i,j+1),(i+1,j),(i+1,j+1) $ (the coordinates are taken modulo $n$ ) is colored red.Find the maximal possible number of a red points in a reddish coloring which looses its property whenever any of the red points is recolored into white.

I have found maximal possible number of red points for some small $n$,tried to make conclusion which could be proved using induction,but failed.

Comment: What were your results for small $n$?